# Sequentially activate specific elements with a dynamically built jQuery promise chain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to play a sound and toggle the class of specific elements in a specific order. Each element should have a class added, play a sound, and then have the class removed before proceeding to do the same on the next element.

Below is one way to do this:

```
var delay = 400;
$('#green').toggleClass('active').delay(delay).promise().done(function () {
  playSound(this[0].id);
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('#red').toggleClass('active').delay(delay).promise().done(function () {
    playSound(this[0].id);
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('#blue').toggleClass('active').delay(delay).promise().done(function () {
      playSound(this[0].id);
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      $('#yellow').toggleClass('active').delay(delay).promise().done(function () {
        playSound(this[0].id);
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I'd prefer to simply pass in an array of element IDs to generate the above code dynamically. Based on a lot of related answers here, I believe this code is more in the right direction, but everything runs all at once.

```
startAnimation();

function playSound(color) {
  var sound = document.getElementById(color + 'Sound');
  sound.load();
  sound.play();
}

function computerClick(color) {
  playSound(color);
  $('#' + color).toggleClass('active').delay(500).promise().done(function () {
    $('#' + color).toggleClass('active');
  });
}

function startAnimation() {
  var colors = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow'];
  var p = $.when(1);
  var results = [];
  colors.forEach(function(color) {
    p = p.then(function() {
      return computerClick(color);        
    });
  });
}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xdfbkL2q/)

Can someone here tell me what I'm doing wrong or if I need a completely different approach?

Comment: You can use `.queue()` to call an array of functions sequentially. At `js` at Question , a jQuery promise object does not appear to be returned from `computerClick()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize `.queue()` to sequentially chain jQuery promises . Note, at `js` at jsfiddle `green` was passed as parameter to `playSound()` , though `green` does not appear defined ?

Added `.load()` before `.play()` at `audio` element; `return` statement to return jQuery promise object from `computerClick()`

```js
$(function() {
startAnimation();

function playSound(color) {
  var sound = document.getElementById(color + 'Sound');
  sound.load(); sound.play();
}

function computerClick(color) {
  playSound(color);
 return $('#' + color).toggleClass('active').delay(500, "_fx")
           .dequeue("_fx")
           .promise("_fx").done(function () {
             $('#' + color).toggleClass('active');
           });
}

function startAnimation() {
  var colors = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow'];
  var results = [];
  $({}).queue("_fx", $.map(colors, function(el) {
    return function(next) {
      computerClick(el).then(next)     
    } 
  })).dequeue("_fx")  
}

playSound("green");
})
```

```css
.color-button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.active {
  opacity: 1!important;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: .6;
}

#yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: .6;
}

#green {
  background-color: green;
  opacity: .6;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: .6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color-button" id="green"></div>
<div class="color-button" id="red"></div>
<div class="color-button" id="yellow"></div>
<div class="color-button" id="blue"></div>

<audio id="greenSound" preload="auto" src="#" type="audio/wav"></audio>
<audio id="redSound" preload="auto" src="#" type="audio/wav"></audio>
<audio id="yellowSound" preload="auto" src="#" type="audio/wav"></audio>
<audio id="blueSound" preload="auto" src="#" type="audio/wav"></audio>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xnr3xpv5/2/

Comment: Thank you for your `.queue()` guidance. Looking forward to a lot of reading today. Your code is exactly what I was hoping to accomplish. It works great. Thanks!